# Indoor panoramas using Google Api v3 are not displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, google-api

I am using the Google Api V3 to display indoor panoramas.

Check the following link. It looks good in all the tested browsers, except Internet Explorer:
http://www.virtualbctours.com/rotation/towne-centre-mall.php?panoid=k7N67Z3yvy3PMXt0bwLggQ

Instead of the panoramas, I am getting a gray screen in Internet Explorer. I checked the code, and I cannot find the problem if any. Can someone check it out?

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Can someone point me the right direction to ask questions related with Google API v3?